# How can I quickly select from the dropdown of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using macbook air, when I type keyword `function` , I want select the second item in the dropdown, now I can only use the `arrow key` to select, 
is there any way I can select it more efficient?

[image]

Comment: I really doubt it.  You could make a macro to do that with the macros extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros#overview  .  Like Let me know if you are interested in that.  Something like Ctrl-3 to focus and select the third item, etc.

Comment: `"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"`?